# I want to use SwiftData and realize two tables

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I want to use SwiftData to realize two separate tables, but if I put them directly as follows, I get several errors such as Declaration name '_body' is not covered by macro 'Query', No exact matches in call to instance method 'modelContainer'. I don't think I can place them easily like this, but if I want to realize two tables, how should I implement it?

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
final class Item {
    var timestamp: Date
    
    init(timestamp: Date) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}

final class Test {
    // Id
    var id: Int
    
    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }
}

import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var items: [Item]
    @Query private var TestItems: [Test]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Item at \(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))")
                    } label: {
                        Text(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(timestamp: Date())
            let newItem2 = Test(id: 1)
            modelContext.insert(newItem)
            modelContext.insert(newItem2)
        }
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            for index in offsets {
                modelContext.delete(items[index])
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
        .modelContainer(for: Item.self, inMemory: true)
        .modelContainer(for: Test.self, inMemory: true)
}
```

Comment: in your `@main struct YourApp: App {...}`
 did you setup the `try ModelContainer(...)` and pass that to your `ContentView`? In `YourApp` show the code where you declare the ModelContainer and how you pass it to ContentView, it may help understand the problem.

Comment: Test is missing @Model

Comment: And you shouldn't create a model container for each model class, use `.modelContainer(for: [Item.self, Test.self], inMemory: true)` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I added @Model and the error is gone. So this was necessary for one.
Also, I couldn't insert it as is, but thanks to the .modelContainer(for: [Item.self, Test.self], inMemory: true) modification, I also solved it. Very helpful.